# Apache mod_proxy + mod_cache (socache and disk)

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy, mod-cache

I have here a three node apache mod_proxy load balancing cluster. now i want enable mod_cache to get more load from the backend to the frontend.

So thats my config for the cache:

```
<IfModule mod_cache.c>
    <IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
            CacheDefaultExpire 3600
            CacheEnable disk https://
            CacheEnable disk /
            CacheRoot "/mnt/ram/"
            CacheDirLevels 2
            CacheDirLength 1
            CacheMaxFileSize 1000000
            CacheMinFileSize 1
            CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
            CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
            CacheIgnoreQueryString Off
            CacheIgnoreHeaders None
            CacheLastModifiedFactor 0.1
            CacheDefaultExpire 3600
            CacheMaxExpire 86400
            CacheStoreNoStore On
            CacheStorePrivate On
    </IfModule>
```

loaded apache modules:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 cache_disk_module (shared)
 cache_socache_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 fcgid_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bybusyness_module (shared)
 lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bytraffic_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
```

So the problem is that any request to the website goes to the backend too, so there is no performance optimizing.

Is there a way i can handle this with mod_cache?

Apacheversion: 2.4.10 (Debian8)
Backend: Typo3 Website.